# Sequelize: Check and add BelongsToMany (N to N) relation

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

My application got **many Users** who can **like many Posts** (N to N). That's why I assigned the following "belongsToMany" Relations for my Models ([Sequelize Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)):

```
// Post Model
models.Post.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.PostLikes});

// User Model
models.User.belongsToMany(models.Post, { through: models.PostLikes});
```

Inside my Post Controller I got the following use case for the "likePost" function:

1. Check if the Post exists. (seems to work)
2. If so, check if the User already liked this Post.
3. If not, assign the N to N relation between User and the Post. (seems to work)

   ```
   // User likes Post
   exports.likePost = async (req, res) => {
    const postToLike = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    // Check if the Post exists
    if (!postToLike) {
     return res.status(404).json({ error: { message: 'Post not found.' }});
    }

    // Did user already like the post?
    // HERE IS THE NOT WORKING PART:
    if (await req.user.hasPost(postToLike).isFulfilled()) {
     return res.status(422).json({ error: { message: 'Already liked post.' }});
    }

    // add Like
    await req.user.addPost(postToLike);
    return res.send(postToLike);
   };
   ```

Now I got the **Problem**, that I am not able to check if a User already liked a Post. "req.user.hasPost(postToLike).isFulfilled()" always returns false, even if indeed I can see the correct relation in my "PostLikes" DB Table. So how can I correctly:

1. Check if a User already liked a Post.
2. Assign this relation.
3. And remove the relation with Sequelize?

BTW this is how my PostLikes Table looks like:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | userId | postId |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      2 |      3 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: You need a many-to-many table relating `Users` and `Posts`.  That's easy to do in MySQL; I don't know how to convince the abstraction package you are using to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, there is no mention of **isFulfilled()**.
Did you try to do `req.user.hasPost(postToLike)` ?
([Sequelize Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#check-associations))

Comment: I logged `req.user.hasPost(postToLike)` and noticed "isFulfilled()" is the result of a pending promise. So I change this part to `await req.user.hasPost(postToLike)`. Basically this fixed the whole problem as it returns the expected result now.

Comment: isFullfilled() is generally not accessed directly. **await** expects a promise, and by calling isFullfilled(), it was not getting a promise to wait on. Can you please accept the answer if it resolved the issue, Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, i know its been a while but why is it a many to many relationship, since a user can have many posts but a post belongs to one user?